# Problem w/ mouse and Pavilion g6

Tags: drivers, 16.04, usb, mouse, touchpad

I just fresh installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a HP Pavilion g6 PC (Prod# D6R46EA).

Once the login pop (greeter screen) the left click on mouse (either touchpad or usb) is irresponsive.

Should I switch to console Ctrl+Alt+F1, the back to Ctrl+Alt+F7 the mouse works as expected.

When I log in, I start Firefox (w/ a left click) that ask to recover closed tab from previous session. Again the left click on mouse is irresponsive.
I can to the Ctrl+Alt+F1,F7 again and everything is ok.
I can also ssh to the PC and issue:
echo -n "0000:00:1a.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/unbind
echo -n "0000:00:1d.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/unbind
echo -n "0000:00:1a.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/bind
echo -n "0000:00:1d.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/bind
And again the mouse click works.

I tried to implement the fixup (reset usb) thru greeter-startup-script, rc.local, session-startup-script but none of those worked.

I am desesperated to find a solution. The Ctrl+Alt+F1,F7 been really pan-optimal assuming the system is to be used by some non geek persons.

If anyone has a solution I'll be delighted to hear from it.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Studio 16.04 w/xfce4:

System settings-> Power manager -> Security tab.

Uncheck "Lock screen when system is going for sleep" (sic).

This worked on both my systems (Laptops: old Sony, fresher Dell).

I also removed X-screensaver, though I'm unsure if this was really necessary.

I imagine it's not too different on any other X-window flavor - disable the screen lock on suspend/sleep in power manager security settings.

Hope this helps.